# No Hot Water in Kitchen Faucet, hot water runs to dishwasher but not to faucet

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

Problem: Our single handle kitchen faucet has no hot water

Details:

1. hot and cold water fine in rest of house
2. checked under sink and hot water is running to dishwasher BUT with hot water valve open all the way and faucet is turned to hot, only slightest trickle comes out and I don't feel any water movement in flexible hose connecting hot water to faucet
3. earlier today we had opposite issue with no cold and only hot, after I turned valves off and on there was almost not water coming out of faucet but after putting space heater under sink, cold water running perfectly but now there's no hot.

I'm not sure if I should start with water valve or faucet (it's a single handle Ball type).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Has this always been this way? If not, what triggered the problem?

Comment: Hello! The problem started yesterday morning, initially it was the reverse (no cold water and only hot) situation.  After I closed and re-opened the hot and cold water shut off valves under the sink, there was no hot water flow from the faucet. The hot water never came back to the faucet, though it does flow to the dishwasher

Comment: Your comment below about outside freezing is important, and is probably the answer. You should edit all this information into your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the flex hose from your hot supply valve to the faucet and test for flow with the faucet disconnected. Ideally you do this with spare 3/8" hose, but a towel, sponge, bucket, and some care will also work.

If your unconnected valve supplies decent water flow when disconnected from your faucet, the problem is in your faucet. Figure out the brand/model and you can get a repair kit.

If hot water doesn't flow even when the valve is disconnected from the faucet, then you have a problem with the valve or plumbing.

My guess is, unless your water lines were actually frozen, the heater is a red herring and the reason you have all hot or all cold is because there's a worn-out washer in your faucet's mixing valve. Possibly a chunk of it has broken and is moving somewhat freely within the valve, blocking one side or the other.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Before I disconnect anything, want to give 2 more pieces of info that may or may not change the direction...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Before I disconnect anything, want to give 2 more pieces of info that may or may not change the direction... 1. Our outside faucet was frozen yesterday morning and it shares the same wall as the kitchen faucet and space heater appeared to have helped with the flow of the cold water  2. When I turn on the kitchen faucet for hot water, I don't feel any water movement from the hot water valve under the sink, but when I turn on dishwasher, I feel the hot water movement from the valve that goes to the dishwasher, both valves connect to same hot water pipe.